# Studies on negative vs positive framing of registered user benefits?

Tags: user-research

I'm looking into the influence of framing effects on the willingness of guest users to register with a website. Specifically, I'd like to know how the positive or negative framing of user benefits can impact guest users' willingness to become a registered user.

For example, a web page may present the message, "you *cannot* do X because you are not a registered user", or it may say, "you *may* do X after you register."

Does anyone have links or references to relatively recent studies on this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Positive versus Negative rewards in general

Finding data where a company tried using both a negative *and* positive registration request without changing anything else to compare the data is going to be hard to come by.  There are, however, [other studies](http://www.psychology.gatech.edu/psyc3031/Behaviorism%20Behavior%20and%20Philosophy/1975%20-%20Vol%203%20No%201/04%20Positive%20and%20Negative%20Reinforcement,%20a%20Distinction%20That%20Is%20No%20Longer%20Necessary.PDF) which compare the effects of positive and negative reinforcement.

In the old fable the [tortoise and the hare](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tortoise_and_the_Hare), the tortoise is comparable to Positive reinforcement while the Hare is faster like Negative reinforcement but doesn't last.

**Negative reinforcement is ultimately based on fear.**  Fear is a powerful motivator as in the case of a high pressured sales pitch or evil sounding political commercial. `"Time is running out!"` `"Last item in stock!"`  Eventually people figure you out and leave, tell you anything to make you go away, or simply give up and stop trying altogether.

**Positive reinforcement, on the other hand, is based on encouragement.** It may take a little longer to get the desired result but the relationship built in the process is totally worth it!

---

### 2. "Register or leave" vs. "Register to make future visits easier"

There is one study that is pretty close to what the original question is asking.  It shows the difference between making registration mandatory or optional...

### The $300 Million Button

> The designers fixed the problem simply. They took away the Register button. In its place, they put a Continue button with a simple message: "You do not need to create an account to make purchases on our site. Simply click Continue to proceed to checkout. To make your future purchases even faster, you can create an account during checkout."

Not only did they remove the register button but they replaced it with a message of **empathy** instantly putting them ahead of anyone else still choosing to make registration a requirement.

---

### 3. Without Registration, Anarchy will ensue

Another community news site named Tropix [released some data](http://blog.topix.com/2006/03/topixnet-forums-on-fire-the-ni-chan-paradox.html) on the quantity and quality of their content before and after removing the registration process.

- Since removing registration, volume has exploded and passed a quarter-of-a-million aggregate posts (**~2500% increased volume**)
- And the quality of posts? The post kill-rate (removal) actually dropped -hovering below 2%. This is less than half of the number incurred when registration was in place.  (**~50% better quality**)

[image: tropix]

---

### 4. The benefit to registering must be so clear that it goes without saying.

A perfect example of this is gmail.  Users don't even think twice about what benefit they get out of registering.  Sure there is a page somewhere telling people why they should register but it's for the minority.  In fact, most people searching for an online email service are either trying to check their email by logging in to their account or looking to register an account.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't have a recent study on this topic - but I think that a positive framing will have a higher conversion rate than a negative framing. Why is that?

- you GIVE something (more features), rather than DENIE it
- you don't want people to leave your site with an negative mindset (you can not do this, you can not do that)
- it's like telling a child :"you cannot watch tv because you didn't do the dishes" instead of "You can watch TV, when you are done with the dishes"

There is a lot of good literature on framing on the internet (you probably already found some good links and were just looking for a study on your specific topic). So my suggestion: Go with positive framing in this context.

Hope it helps, even though I didn't provide a link :)

Comment: Thanks, Pascal! I'm in agreement with you for very much the same reasons as you listed above. Still, the scientist in me desires hard data, p-values and all (I've seen statistical analyses turn strong intuitions and seemingly rock-solid reasoning upside down). You're right though that the question I asked is quite specific, and maybe there are no studies on precisely that. Perhaps I should just conduct a poll...